# Flask route doesn't seem to accept -'s in the routes

Tags: flask

I'm trying to expose a .well-known directory to serve a file needed to enable apple pay on my site. Apple pay needs the following domain to be accessible: `mydomain.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`

Unfortunately, flask is making this a bit difficult. To expose this path, I have setup a route like so:

```
@app.route('/.well-known/<path:filename>')
def well_known_stub(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.root_path + "\\well-known", filename, conditional=True)
```

Unfortunately it when I try to access `mydomain.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`, I get a 500 error. The issue seems to be that flask fails to recognize any route that contains a `'-'`. Is there a good way to work around this limitation? I expect I may need a converter, but I don't really have a good understanding of how converters work.

EDIT:
As a follow-up, I plan to serve this with nginx on my production code. This is primarily to help with testing/local dev

Comment: The `-` shouldn't be a problem. I've used it many times. But I don't think the period is allowed in a route. Can you do just: `@app.route('/well-known/<path:filename>')` and report back if that works?

Comment: Interesting. If I stay with my approach, I can request `http://localhost:5000/.well-known/apple` and see the request hit my server-side code, but the dashified `.../.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association` fails. If I change the route to `@app.route('/well-known/<path:filename>')` like you suggested, the dashified route works. I'm not sure if this will work for Apple's requirements though, but I'll try to finish the rest of the boilerplate to test. Still a little strange that the dashified route fails with the `.`

Comment: Yes, it is strange. I'm not sure what's going on under the hood there.